# jsPDF SVG invalid base64-string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, base64, jspdf

I'm trying to add a SVG to a PDF document. I'm using the jsPDF library. The SVG is retrieved from a D3 chart rendered on the webpage. I use the `window.btoa()` function to convert my SVG to a base64 string. In order to make it a valid image I add `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` to the start of the string.

```
const unit = "pt";
const size = "A4"; // Use A1, A2, A3 or A4
const orientation = "landscape"; // portrait or landscape

...

const doc = new jsPDF(orientation, unit, size);
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
var img = "data:image/svg+xml;" + window.btoa(s);
doc.addImage(img, 0, 0, 100);
```

This results in an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String
```

I've tried simply displaying the content through a `<img src="data:..."/>` which works. I've also tried using external tools to convert svgs to base64 and using that specific string. This results in the same error.

I recognize there are similar questions but there seems to be none that relates to the rejection of the base64 string.

Comment: There maybe a bug in jsPDF.
Check out this file of addImage function which has a validating function.
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/e973818a7e6b48d62a6ef7daca0d7e2290d016b4/src/modules/addimage.js#L590